# How to make programmatic access to an appengine application that is secure and authenticated

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have several appengine applications that require login, and these work just fine when accessed from a browser. However, we also want to access the same applications from a client application rather than an end-user. For the purposes of this question, let's say we want to use curl commands from a CLIENT machine to access our e.g. https://example.appspot.com/whatever URLs. We also intend to migrate to a custom domain when everything is working.

Ideally, we would complete login and all URL accesses with Curl commands on the client machine with no user intervention at all (e.g. from a cron job). I understand this to be quite challenging since the old ClientLogin feature which made this easy is now deprecated.

We have successfully implemented access to Google APIs directly from a client machine via Curl with an authorization token after authorization callbacks to a local webserver on the client machine. I suppose a similar approach should allow access to the URLs of a secured appserver application. However we haven't been able to make this work and (to my mind) surprisingly cannot find a single worked example of a program authenticating with and then using an appserver application anywhere unless with the deprecated ClientLogin.

Finally, we want to install an absolute minimum of software on the client (Windows) machine. Ideally curl.exe only, python and standard library plus some simple python scripts at a pinch. Javascript/XMLHTTP in a browser would be fine too.

Endpoints don't seem to be an answer - they don't permit a custom domain - and would mandate a major rewrite. However, automating access to the regular end user URLs seems a reasonable requirement, if only for automated testing. We just don't see how to do it.

Any help/example for the current non-deprecated App Engine environment would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this by any chance? Since today the deprecated ClientLogin seems to have been completely removed and the http://<app-id>.appspot.com/_ah/login url throws a 500 Server Error. Google's (lack of) documentation is atrocious.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to be using the App Engine OAuth support, which is implemented within the handler itself, not via app-level auth configuration:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/#oauth2